# Is there an Editor or IDE capable of returning external program output?

Tags: php, ide, editor

I've got around 14 IDE's installed for testing on my WinXP box right now, from Notepad++ to Netbeans, Aptana to Zend Studio. I'm trying to find one that will do what I need, but no luck finding a solution yet.

My goal is this:

> The IDE is open and I'm working on a
>   PHP file. Click a button or hit a
>   hotkey...
>
> My IDE sends the file I'm working on
>   to an external app (Firefox, Lynx,
>   Chrome, etc.) with any command-line
>   parameters I specify, processes it,
>   then returns the output (HTML source,
>   in this case) back to my IDE in an
>   output window and/or new file tab.

Seems like a simple request, right? ;)

For clarity, I'm not interested in downloading Win PHP binaries and simply running the script inside my IDE. I've got a virtual server setup (Virtualbox) which perfectly mirrors my live server and really want to use that for generating output and testing. Also, I'm trying to avoid switching back and forth between IDE and browser to check the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with External Tasks in any Eclipse-based IDE. Of course, it won't read your mind, so its up to you to configure the task:

- http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-exttools-running.htm

Also, Zend Studio has support for Virtual Machines, though Im not sure if it's relevant to your question.

Answer (score 1):

The [Zeus](http://www.zeusedit.com/) editor can run external applications via it's tool setup and capture the application output to a tool output window.

To add the name of the current file to the tool command line just use the *$fn* macro tag as a marker when setting up the tool command line.

Answer (score 0):

Gvim, what else? Use a command like this:

```
:r ! [some command]
```

And the output from [some command] will be pasted into your current file. Or:

```
:20,25 ! rot13
```

Will take lines 20-25, run them through the external `rot13` command and put the output in it's place.